# MOSS how to edit default page layouts

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

IS it is possible to change the default page layouts that can with MOSS. If so where are they stored to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article by Heather Solomon (a SharePoint MVP) will give you some useful hints on how to create "layouts" or, to be more precise, master pages and how to deploy them: http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/servermstpageforsitecollect_feature.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Open the page using SharePoint Designer.  You'll have access to the Master Page and you'll be able to modify the layout/CSS.

Comment: Be careful using Sharepoint Designer as you get problems moving  the solution to production etc.....

Comment: Only if you actually are using a solution to deploy say custom layouts etc. If the site is an out of the box one, sharepoint designer can be enough. It gets totally unmaintainable fast though :-D. P.S. most files are ok to be edited, they just get ghosted. If however you need to edit a list form (i.e. newform.aspx), do it in a copy of the original and set the list's properties to use your custom form.